# Как вывести значение b после return через getElementById?

Tags: javascript

```
const NOKFunc = (a, b) => {
  let a = document.getElementById("q1").value;
  a = parseInt(a);
  let b = document.getElementById("q2").value;
  b = parseInt(b);

  while (b % a != 0) {
    b *= a;
    return b;
  }
 
}; // document.getElementById("answ").innerHTML =b ;
```

Comment: Без вызова функции с аргументами, никакого `b` не будет... Делай так `document.getElementById("answ").innerHTML = NOKFunc(тут_нужны_аргументы)`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почитайте про алгоритм [Евклида](https://brestprog.by/topics/gcd/)

Вероятно в любом языке `return` это выход из функции, таким образом Ваш цикл даже не переходил на следующую итерацию. Лучше использовать `textContent` для вставки результата а `innerHTML` отставьте для вставки HTML элементов.

Тут еще нужно реализовать условие, думаю справитесь сами.

```js
const NOKFunc = () => {
  let a = document.getElementById("q1").value;
  a = parseInt(a);
  let b = document.getElementById("q2").value;
  b = parseInt(b);
  let t;
  while (b % a !== 0) {
    b %= a;
    t = a
    a = b
    b = t
    //return b;
  }
  document.getElementById("answ").textContent = a;  
};
```

```html
A<input id="q1" type="text" value="25" >(A > B)
<br>
B<input id="q2" type="text" value="10">
<br>
НОК:<p id="answ"></p>
<button onclick="NOKFunc()">Вычислить</button>
```